# scp: Failed to open file /my/Path/test.txt on Windows Server

Tags: linux, ssh, docker, scp

I have been trying to copy a file from a remote Windows Server to my local docker image from my local docker image and I keep getting the error 'scp:Failed to open File /my/Path/test.txt'.My workaround was placing it in Documents and passed the source path '/Documents/test.txt' and it worked for a while. It has stopped working now and I get the same error. I know for a fact that I am able to ssh into the server. Any idea on how to resolve the issue or is there any better method to copy a file from a remote server to my system?

Thanks!

Edit 1: The error is not specific to my docker image. I get the same error when I run it from my local system.

The command is as follows :

```
scp user@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/Documents/Test.txt /path/on/docker/image/
```

The result is as follows :

```
scp: Failed to open file /Documents/Test.txt.
```

Edit 2: I have tried the paths 'Documents/Test.txt' as well as 'c/Users/user/Documents/Test.txt' and I still get the same error

Comment: Welcome to the U&L SE. Can you provide the Dockerfile you're using to build this image? Please edit the question to add that information.

Comment: Well I pulled this image from Dockerhub. I did not write the docker file to build the image. This error is not specific to docker as I just tested and found out.

Comment: In that case, can you rewrite your question to be clearer and focus on the specifics? You can refer to the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidance.

Comment: I just added this data into my edit

Comment: Does the file exist at the absolute path `/Documents/Test.txt` or should that be `Documents/Test.txt`, i.e. relative to your home directory?

Comment: I've tried both and I still get the error.

Comment: Okay, so where is the file exactly and what is it called?

Comment: The file is in Documents and it is called Test.txt